# Is "kbeznak parmatonic" still a neologism if I created it a week ago?

Tags: neologisms

I understand that neologism means a *newly coined word*. But if I coined kbeznak parmatonic one week ago, is it still a neologism? I even created a website explaining what the word is, so it is no longer new, right?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It looks like it was a class assignment to push the nonsense phrase up the search results. The link doesn't add anything to the English question, so I have removed it.

Comment: I do not understand how it harmed or how it was a spam. Anyway I have removed it. Feel free to remove the question if that is a better option. Sorry about the spam I guess.

Comment: @anon - The question as written right now – sans the link – is a fair question. The question with the link – cross-posted on other sites across the Stack Exchange, no less – is using SE as a platform to generate web traffic, not get answers to problems that you actually face. As a member of SE for more than six years, you should have known better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your new word (or phrase) *could be* an example of a [nonce word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word), also called an *occasionalism* (not "neologism") – "a lexeme created for a single occasion to solve an immediate problem of communication".

However, it is not even that. The link to Medium you provided indicates that this coinage does not even fulfill the basic requirements for being a word—it does not mean anything. Thus, it does not even solve an immediate problem in communication; it creates one.

A word, even one you come up with in the moment, would often be clear for the person you're speaking to because it is **based** off an existing word (e. g., has a common root), or it's clear because of the **context.** In this case, there is no context, no relation to existing lexemes, and there is a disregard for common sound combinations in the English language (which would not have "k" and "b" together at the beginning of a syllable) and morphology.

A neologism, first and foremost, should be a word—and a word is a unity of an outward sign (a sequence of phonemes / letters (if in writing)) and a meaning. **If there is no meaning, it is not a word (in a more significant sense than the phrase "it's not a word" is normally used in English).** Then, *if* a word turns out to be a productive means of expressing a certain meaning that is not covered by other existing words, it spreads and becomes recognizable to a significant number of people—at the very least a subculture or something. Then it can be recognized as a neologism and included in dictionaries.

Even if you create a bot that posts this coinage all over the internet, if it's not used by real people to *mean something*, it is not a neologism, not an occasionalism. It's nothing; no matter the number of Google results (currently 64, mostly on github in users' profiles and/or usernames).